# ''Its solid finish and colour also gives a chic addition to your kitchenware.''

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> Its solid finish and colour also gives a chic addition to your kitchenware.

Is it gives or give in the question because it is really confusing me?

Answer (score 1):

It could be either, depending on whether you are grouping the finish and colour into a single entity.

You’re choosing between:

> It gives

> They give

You’d use “gives” if you were grouping the two things together and saying that ***together*** they produce the result you’re describing (and one wouldn’t without the other).

For your example I’m leaning toward “give”, perhaps because it sounds like quite a formal sentence, and I feel “give” to be a bit more proper in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful. : )

Comment: You’re welcome! Please mark the answer as correct if it is so. :)